# No route matches [patch] "/happy/node/10003

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

## routes

```
put '/happy/node/:node_id', to: 'nodes#happy', as: :happy
```

## node controller

```
def happy 
   @node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
      if @node.update_attributes(:node_status => "happy", 
                                 :location_id => params[:location_id], 
                                 :hostname => params[:hostname])
         redirect_to node_url
      end
end
```

## view - form

```
<%= form_for(@node, url: happy_path(@node), method: :patch, do |f| %>
<%= f.label :location_id, "Location" %>
<%= collection_select :location_id, Location.order(:name), :id, :name, :prompt => "Select Location" %>
<%= f.submit "Save Changes" %>
```

I am trying to update the node form using a custom action. When i tried this it failed miserably. I will be extremely grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you are using put, so your method should also be put:

```
<%= form_for(@node, url: happy_path(@node), method: :put, do |f| %>
```

Comment: I also tried to include put on both, but the form won't submit.

Comment: What is on your logs when submitting not happened? And I just wondered why you need this part `url: happy_path(@node)`.

Comment: No template found for NodesController#happy, rendering head :no_content

Comment: Completed 204 No Content

Comment: It also states No route matches [Get] "/happy/node/10003"

Comment: Did you checked if your data changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `patch` route, if you want to continue using `PATCH`:

```
patch '/happy/node/:node_id', to: 'nodes#happy', as: :happy
```

Comment: So i would add patch to the route and keep the method patch on the form?

Comment: I added patch to my routes and form and I get 'No route matches [put]'